Help reading schematics for design reviews
I'm reaching out to those with more experience in reading electronic schematics. As the Compliance engineer on the team, I primarily handle testing, pre-testing, and certifications. Recently, I've been included in design reviews, which is new territory for me. The schematics are quite extensive (40-50 pages), and I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed.
While my input isn't crucial at this stage, I anticipate a greater role in the future and want to be well-prepared. Any advice on how to approach these documents would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Unfortunately, this is a bit of an open-ended question that's opinion-based and not really suitable for this site.  You can try EEVBlog maybe, or just Googling "reading schematics" for more info.

Is Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics any help, in terms of what issues to comment on during a design review?

@ChesterGillon I need to comment on EMC/EMI potential issues.

It's not your job to design the circuits but it could easily be part of your responsibility to ensure that the design stage has been conducted correctly. Ask questions about how the design was done, what calculations were made, what simulations were done, what testing has been done and what considerations were made in the design for the stuff that concerns you  i.e. make sure that what gets handed over to you is not a dud and, make sure that what gets handed over to you has been designed in a way that properly considered the stages you are involved with.

@DRF There are schematics that are good/easy to read and then there are bad/difficult to read. However, the point is not how they are drawn but what kind of circuit they depict. And schematics don't show if somebody drew the PCB in a way that it will pass EMI and EMC tests or not, or what should have been done in the schematics and on the PCB to fix it.

@Justme yes I agree with you, what is important to me is that I need to figure out if I can spot obvious mistakes, like missing ESD protection , EFT protection , surge, etc

This type of question about reading schematics has been asked before, although not in the context of compliance design review.

Your job is not to spot obvious mistakes, but ask the questions "What did you do for ...", "How did you test it", "Outside certification".  As in, these are things we need to consider to make it manafacturable.  What did we do to make that happen.

The requirements are highly dependent on the specific project, whether it is analog, digital (MCU, FPGA, etc.). Initially, it is crucial to ensure a functioning system, which necessitates verifying the schematic against application notes, datasheets, and other relevant documentation. in this step even you maybe need to check some simulation results of the circuit. To be more specific if you want to have near to standard schematic drawings I suggests watching several videos of the following you tube channel:
https://www.youtube.com/@PhilsLab
In the next step, it is essential to address EMC compliance features, such as ESD protection.

Approach it as you would any engineering.
Do a coarse readthrough first. Think system level architecture, look for obviously things that stick out. Analyze from the standpoint of your area of responsibility, but don't be afraid to note more things.
Break the design up into smaller sections. Go through it again, focusing more detailed on each section. Analyze again from the standpoint of your area. Break up into smaller sub-circuits and analyze as far down as possible.
Check the design against design documents to verify that design requirements and specs have been fulfilled. Create checklists for typical points that need to be checked for designs, and  re-use and re-shape those lists from review to review.
Also, you get better at reading schematics by practice. The more you do it the quicker you recognise design patterns and the more efficient you get at the compartmentalization process. This is also why you should be critical to graphically badly formed schematics, or schematics that doesn't follow best practice and/or your companys internal design guidelines.
PS. Something many organisations struggle with - The design review process is done before you have the design review meetings. Be prepared! Have the remarks and comments ready before the meeting.
